# Prove that $[0, \infty)$ is not order isomorphic to $(\frac{1}{2}, \infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Prove that $[0, \infty)$ is not order isomorphic to $(\frac{1}{2}, \infty)$.

My attempt: Let $f: [0, \infty)\rightarrow (\frac{1}{2}, \infty)$ is an order isomorphism.

Let $a= f(0) \in (\frac{1}{2}, \infty)$. Now choose $b$ such that $(\frac{1}{2}<b<a$. Now  I can  not proceed further.

How to construct a contradiction?

Comment: If $x := f^{-1}(b)$, then $x > 0$ but $f(x) = b < a = f(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

There is just not a minimum element in $(\frac{1}{2},\infty)$. Since $f(0)$ must be the least element of $(\frac{1}{2},\infty)$, let's say $f(0)=b$. Suppose $b \in (\frac{1}{2},\infty)$ is the minimum of the interval. By definition of open set, you have that $(b-\delta , b + \delta) \subseteq (\frac{1}{2},\infty)$ with $\delta > 0$ sufficiently small, then $b- \frac{\delta}{2} \in (\frac{1}{2},\infty)$ but this is a contradiction (because we have found an element in $(\frac{1}{2},\infty)$ smaller than $b=f(0)$). So they cannot be order isomorphic

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_1 = f^{-1}(b)$. As $b \lt a$ and $f$ is an order isomorphism, you need to have $b_1 = f^{-1}(b) \lt f^{-1}(a) = 0$. A contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an order isomorphism if $f$ is bijective and if $x<y$ in $X$ then $f(x)<f(y)$ in $Y$. Does it true that $f^{-1}:Y\rightarrow X$ is also an order  isomorphism?

Comment: Of course true.

Comment: @user1234 For sure. Just proceed by contradiction for the proof.

Comment: @LostinSpace No, it's not true. Consider the relation on $X=\{1,2,3\}$ where $1<3$, $2<3$, but $1$ and $2$ are not comparable; consider also $Y=\{1,2,3\}$ with the standard order. Then the identity map is a bijection satisfying $f(a)<f(b)$ when $a<b$ in $X$, but the inverse map doesn't.

Comment: @egreg It is true for linear orders. Which is the case for the current question.

Comment: Well. I think if $X, Y$ are linear order, then inverse of a order isomorphism is also an isomorphism. Isn't it?

Comment: @LostinSpace Yes, but it has to be spelled out.

Answer (score 1):

An order isomorphism between two ordered sets must preserve any property describable using only the order properties.

One of these ordered sets has a minimum element and the other does not, so they can't be order isomorphic. There's no need to explain why any particular possible order isomorphism isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

An order isomorphism $f\colon X\to Y$ is a bijection such that, for all $a,b\in X$, it holds
$$
a<b \iff f(a)<f(b)
$$
which is equivalent to saying that $f$ is increasing and the inverse map is increasing as well.

Requiring that $f$ is bijective and increasing is not sufficient.

A simple counterexample is the set $X=\{1,2\}$ with the relation $\{(1,1),(2,2)\}$ and $Y=\{1,2\}$ with the relation $\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)\}$. The identity map $f\colon X\to Y$ satisfies “for all $a,b\in X$, if $a<b$ then $f(a)<f(b)$”, but the inverse map doesn't satisfy the similar condition.

In your case, set $a=f(0)$ and choose $b$ such that $b<a$ (which surely exists). Then $f^{-1}(b)<f^{-1}(a)$ by definition of order isomorphism and this is a contradiction, because $f^{-1}(b)<0$ is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.All we need  that $f$ is bijective and $a\le b\iff f(a) \le f(b) $ . For linear ordered set if $a\le b$ implies $f(a) \le f(b) $ is enough, other way follows easily.